# animated li with javascript - why do they all move at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am a super n00b with javascript, hoping someone can help me!

I don't understand why all of the li items are animating at the same time, obviously I only want the one I have moused over to animate.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KBmV3/1/)

**Javascript**

```
$("li").mouseenter(
 function()
 {
     $(this).find("div").stop(true, false).animate({"margin-bottom" : "20px"}, 'slow')
  });

$("li").mouseleave(
 function()
 {
     $(this).find("div").stop(true, false).animate({"margin-bottom": "0"}, 'fast');
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation {
width:100%;}

#navigation ul {
list-style-type:none;}

#navigation ul li {
display:inline-block;
margin-right:1%;}

#navigation ul li div {
height:125px;
width:120px;
background-color:#ccc;}
```

Comment: change your css `#navigation ul li` to `#navigation ul li { margin-bottom:1%;}` and you may understand ..

Comment: This might help .. [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Aha! float:left works perfectly!
Thanks so much @putvande

Comment: Have you understood why ?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of your question and based on the fiddle that you have provided, it appears that you are trying to animate the Y coordinates of the divs in the list. In order to do that you would want to use the CSS top property and animate that accordingly.

```
$("ul li").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('div').stop(true, false).animate({
        'top': '+=' + 20
    }, 'slow');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('div').stop(true, false).animate({
        'top': 0
    }, 'fast');
});
```

In order to animate the top property in jQuery animate, you must specify the position of the element. Please note here that I have added that.

```
#navigation ul li div {
    height:125px;
    width:120px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position: relative;
}
```

I have also taken the margin property off of the li elements in order to get them to display in one line.

```
#navigation ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Also, jQuery allows for chaining, so instead of writing the selector out twice and working with two instances of the object, you can chain the events on one instance of the jQuery object.